# ASP and Access testing environment; how do I update the DSN?

Tags: database, ms-access, asp-classic, ado

This web app/page was given to me revision. Right now I am trying to create a test environment so I have copied the ASP files and the MBD file associated with the site into another file on my server.

How do I update the ASP files to reflect the test MBD file I've just created? For example it is still pulling from the old database.

In the test ASP page I am working on, this is in the code:

```
rsAllStudents.Open "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY group_num", "DSN=MGMT5133"
```

However, I need it to reference a different db... So I guess, how and where do I make the "DSN" designation change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using DSN-less connection, this way you're not tied to a specific DSN:

```
rsAllStudents.Open "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY group_num", "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\PathToYourDb\mydatabase.mdb"
```

If you don't want to be tied to specific path (e.g. when you move your site) you can use relative path and Server.MapPath method. For example if your MDB located in the same virtual directory as your ASP file you can do:

```
rsAllStudents.Open "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY group_num", "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="  & Server.MapPath("mydatabase.mdb")
```

Comment: Thank you, I just figured out how to do that.  Now in the ASP page, what should I be replacing "DSN=MGMT5133" with?  Now I have:
MM_conn_STRING = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("test_mgmt5133.mdb")

Comment: Replace entire `"DSN=MGMT5133"` (including quotes) with `MM_conn_STRING` as is, without quotes. Making it `rsAllStudents.Open "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY group_num", MM_conn_STRING`

Comment: I am getting... **Server Error
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.**  Although I changed the conn.asp and the asp page I am working on.  Hmmm I'm stumped. But thank you for your help.

Comment: Is test_mgmt5133.mdb located in the same folder as ASP page? Also is this a 32-bit or 64-bit machine?

Comment: My conn.asp page is within the folder "Connections" and looks like this: `<%

' FileName="Connection_odbc_conn_dsn.htm"

' Type="ADO" 

' DesigntimeType="ADO"

' HTTP="true"

' Catalog=""

' Schema=""

Dim MM_conn_STRING

MM_conn_STRING = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("test_mgmt5133.mdb")

%>` and the DB file test_mgmt5133.mdb is within the same folder as the page I am working on.  I am running a 64 bit system. The code I replaced on the index page is `rsAllStudents.Open "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY group_num", MM_conn_STRING`

Comment: Since you're running on 64-bit system "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" provider won't work - it works only on 32-bit systems. You need to download Access driver here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 (on the next page select 64-bit version). Then change your MM_conn_STRING to `MM_conn_STRING = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("test_mgmt5133.mdb")`

Comment: No problem. Please let me know if the solution worked for you - if it did, please check the answer as accepted.

Comment: I tried to install it and it said that I couldn't because "32 bit components" were already installed with the Office Suite. So I tried to create a new file DSN and none of the data source selections are *.mdb so I am not sure what to do at this point other than consult a DB admin here... Thanks again.

Comment: You probably have MS Offise 32bit installed on that machine. This is why you cannot instal 64bit driver. One other possibility is on the Web Server Side (In the IIS) make your application use 32-bit application pool. This way you can go back to using `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`